# How to get latitude and longitude with ionic framework.

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am using following code for getting Lat/Lng on Android device. I got lat/lng on some device but on most of device i am not getting it.

```
var options = { timeout: 3000, enableHighAccuracy: true };

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
});

function onSuccess(position) 
{
    latvalue = position.coords.latitude;
    lngvalue = position.coords.longitude;
    timestamp = position.timestamp;
    alert(latvalue);
}
function onError(error)
{
    alert(error);
}
```

Comment: I am getting always "Timeout expired" error.

Answer (score 1):

just try without "options"

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```